# Continuosly get stream of each insertions from SQL Server table

Tags: c#, sql-server

I want to monitor insertions in an SQL Server table.  Like two columns UserID and Activity from a table (userData) so that as soon as the insertion happens to this table, I get the values that were inserted and passed to C#.

I want to use each insertion for comparison like comparing each insertion with some value and take actions upon them.

PS. I know how to get data from SQL Server and insert data to SQL Server table using C#. But don't know how to achieve it on a real-time basis to take decisions upon them.

Comment: Sounds like a use case for [SqlDependency](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql/detecting-changes-with-sqldependency)

Comment: >>" I get the values" . Get them how?

Comment: @MatthewEvans I get these values in C# program in GridView by using SQLConnection

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`SqlDependency`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql/detecting-changes-with-sqldependency) class and use it's `OnChange` event. Go through the linked MSDN document to see an example on how.

```
dependency.OnChange+=new
           OnChangeEventHandler(OnDependencyChange);
```

Answer (score 0):

Create an Insert Trigger

```
    CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[userDataInsert]
    ON [dbo].[userData]
    FOR INSERT
    AS
    BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON

    select * 
        from    inserted

   -- do whatever you need with inserted


    END
```

Comment: As I am using a C# application to get these new insertions from SQL Server table. So as far as I understand is I just create trigger once in SQL Server and while getting data in Gridview of C# I use the query to select data from the trigger?

Comment: No - triggers should not be used to generate resultsets that are sent back to the inserting application. The idea of a trigger might be useful but your example is not.

Answer (score 0):

Use can also look at **[SqlTableDependency](https://github.com/christiandelbianco/monitor-table-change-with-sqltabledependency)**. It is a c# component raising events when a record is changes. You can find more detail at: https://github.com/christiandelbianco/monitor-table-change-with-sqltabledependency

**SqlTableDependency** is a high-level C# component used to audit, monitor and receive notifications on SQL Server's record table changes. For any record table change, as insert, update or delete operation, a notification containing values for the record changed is delivered to SqlTableDependency. This notification contains insert, update or delete record values.

[image]

This **table record tracking change** system has the advantage to avoid a select to retrieve updated table record, because the updated table values record is delivered by notification.

Comment: A very interesting idea. I will try it.